# In a bash script executed on boot, how do I get the username of the user just logged-in?

Tags: bash, boot

I need to execute a bash script on boot.
To do so I created a file

```
/etc/init.d/blah
```

I edited it and added the following lines

```
#! /bin/sh
# /etc/init.d/blah

touch '/var/lock/blah'
username1=$(id -n -u)
username2=$(whoami)
touch '/var/lock/1'${username1}
touch '/var/lock/2'${username2}

exit 0
```

The script is execute with **root privileges** (which is what I need because I have to use `mount` inside this script) .. but the problem is that I also need to know the **username** of the user who has just logged-in beacuse my goal is to mount a certain folder to a certain mount-point depending on the username, like

```
mount -o bind /home/USERNAME/mount-point /media/data/home/USERNAME/to-be-mounted
```

Going back to the boot script, if I do

```
sudo update-rc.d blah defaults
```

and then reboot and log-in with my username (let's say `john`) both ways to get `username` in my script produce `root` in fact I've got 3 files

```
/var/lock/blah
/var/lock/1root
/var/lock/2root
```

So, how can I get the username of the user who just logged-in? (`john` in my example)


**EDITED:**
I solved in this way:

1. I created a .desktop file for each user I need to perform automount on boot to autostart a script on boot (I'm on LXDE) and put it on /home/{username}/.config/autostart

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Type=Application
Exec=bash "/path/to/mount-bind.sh"
```

2. I stored in that path a bash script called mount-bind.sh and made it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash

_username=$1

if [[ -z "${_username}" ]]; then
    _username="$(id -u -n)"
fi

mkdir -p "/home/${_username}/mount-folder"
sudo mount -o bind "/media/data/home/${_username}/mount-folder" "/home/${_username}/mount-folder"

exit 0
```

3. I added the following line to /etc/sudoers

```
%nopwd ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /bin/mount
```

4. I created the nopwd group and added to it all the users I need

In his way after login I can mount the path under the user home.

Problem with this method is that I have to create the desktop file for each new user and add him/her to nopwd, but it works.

Any further improvement is welcome! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should move from a boot time init script to a script executed at login time under the logged-in user. To allow this, you should look into ways to allow your users to execute the mount command you need. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, one of the following methods may help you:

- Assuming you are on Linux or some other UNIX with a similar feature, add the mountpoint to `/etc/fstab` with the `user` option, allowing normal users to mount the entry.
- Execute `mount` through `sudo` with a suitably narrow `sudoers` configuration as to not allow users to execute any mount commands.
- Write a suid-root program in c which executes the required mount commands when called. This however is very tricky to get right without creating gaping security holes.

Answer (score 2):

Login does not happen at boot time. You cannot foretell which user is going to log in when booting.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Do you think there is way for me to reach my goal? (which is to mount a certain folder to a certain mountpoint on boot depending on the username)

Comment: @LucaBorrione: Definitelly not at boot time. It might be possible at login time, though.

Answer (score -1):

Try Exporting the logindetails and use it.

export username2=$(whoami)

Comment: -1 At boot time, the only user is `root`. Anyway, exporting only affects visibility towards children of the current process. And as a final aside, you cannot use Bash syntax in a sh script.